# Tooltip MUI and React testing library

Tags: material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test an Info HOC on my react app :

```js
const InfoHOC = (HocComponent) => ({ message }) => (
  <>
    <Tooltip title={message}>
      <InfoIcon />
    </Tooltip>
    {HocComponent}
  </>
);

export default InfoHOC;
```

I've simplified it. But as it's using material ui Tooltip component, I can't test if message is displayed on mouseover...

```js
it('should display info message on <div /> mouseover', () => {
  const Component = InfoHoc(<div>jest div</div>)({ message: 'jest infoHoc message' });
  const { getByTitle, getByDisplayValue } = render(Component);
  const icon = getByTitle('jest infoHoc message');
  act(() => {
    fireEvent(
      icon,
      new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
        bubbles: true,
      }),
    );
  });
  expect(getByDisplayValue('jest infoHoc message')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

My last line is wrong... I think it's because mui tooltip display the message in a div at the end of the body, so not really in my rtl tree... BUT the first element of this tree is body !
I know that I should not test mui component, but here is not the purpose, I just want to be sure that InfoHoc has the right comportment, using mui tooltip or something else.

Here is the RTL tree after mouseover action :

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="infoHoc"
    >
      <div>
        jest div
      </div>
      <svg
        aria-hidden="true"
        class="MuiSvgIcon-root icon--right"
        focusable="false"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      >
        <path
          d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The event is good because icon has a title attr with message as value till mouseover is fired. As title attr is not here on my tree, I assume my event is well executed ;p

I am wrong testing that ? If not do you have an idea to solve my problem ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case this can still help you, you need to `findBy` instead of `getBy` as the `Tooltip` is showing the tooltip [after a delay](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/Tooltip/Tooltip.js#L645)

```js
it('should display info message on <div /> mouseover', async () => {
  const Component = InfoHoc(<div>jest div</div>)({ message: 'jest infoHoc message' });
  const { getByTitle, findByDisplayValue } = render(Component);
  const icon = getByTitle('jest infoHoc message');

  act(() => {
    fireEvent(
      icon,
      new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
        bubbles: true,
      }),
    );
  });

  // Wait for the tooltip to show up
  const tooltipText = await findByDisplayValue('jest infoHoc message')

  expect(tooltipText).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Side note 1: I am not sure if you really need the `act` around `fireEvent`. testing-library should do it for you.

Side note 2: you can use [user-event](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event) which has a cleaner syntax (and a `.hover` function)

Comment: I'll test it in my next project ! Thx

Answer (score 10):

I think this is the cleanest way.

```
  it('Renders tooltip when hovering over button', async () => {
    render(<Search />);
    const button = await screen.findByRole('button');
    await userEvent.hover(button);
    const tip = await screen.findByRole('tooltip');
    expect(tip).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Comment: Then you can do something like this to check the tooltip's text:
    expect(tip.textContent).toBe('blah blah');